cpp show backtrace with err line num
ai make following code:
#include <iostream>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdexcept>

// Function to generate and print backtrace
void print_backtrace() {
    const int max_frames = 16;
    void* trace[max_frames];
    char** messages = nullptr;
    int frames = backtrace(trace, max_frames);
    messages = backtrace_symbols(trace, frames);
    if (messages != nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Backtrace:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < frames; ++i) {
            // Print only the part of the message containing the file name and line number
            std::cerr << "[" << i << "] " << messages[i] << "\n";
        }
        free(messages);
    }
}

// Utility function to throw an error with backtrace
void throw_err(const std::string& message) {
    std::cerr << "Error occurred: " << message << std::endl;
    print_backtrace();
    throw std::runtime_error(message);
}

int main() {
    try {
        // Simulating an error
        throw_err("An error occurred!");
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

I out backtrace like
Backtrace:
[0] /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/cmake-build-debug/draft/draft/test_out_backtrace(+0x1ac8) [0x555555555ac8]
[1] /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/cmake-build-debug/draft/draft/test_out_backtrace(+0x1c33) [0x555555555c33]
[2] /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/cmake-build-debug/draft/draft/test_out_backtrace(+0x1ccb) [0x555555555ccb]

I hope cpp out backtrace with err line num, how to do?

From the GNU C library backtrace reference: "Each string contains a printable representation of the corresponding element of buffer. It includes the function name (if this can be determined), an offset into the function, and the actual return address (in hexadecimal)." No mention of line-numbers. You have to use other facilities for that.

If your compiler is new enough to have C++23 support, you could use std::stacktrace.

Other fascilities

Never used it, but my understanding is there's some very cool stuff in boost stacktrace as well.
